# Why does OpenVPN connect, but it doesn't work?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, mac, vpn, openvpn

I have an Ubuntu machine running as an OpenVPN server in another city.  I'm able to access it via ssh.  I'm trying use the VPN from a Mac using Tunnelblick.

The server's local subnet is 192.168.80.x.  The client's is 192.168.0.x.  When the client connects, its IP address is 10.8.0.5.

Tunnelblick connects, but I'm not able to `ping 8.8.8.8`, load a webpage,  or access any of the remote LAN's devices, except the VPN server using the address 10.8.0.1.

The client's config file:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote [my server's external IP address] 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
comp-lzo
verb 3
redirect-gateway local def1
```

The server's:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
dh dh2048.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "route 192.168.80.0 255.255.255.0"
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

What do I need to change?

Edit:
On the server:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1

$ sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

$ ip route
default via 192.168.80.1 dev enp2s0  proto static  metric 100
10.8.0.0/24 via 10.8.0.2 dev tun0
10.8.0.2 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.0.1
169.254.0.0/16 dev tun0  scope link  metric 1000
192.168.80.0/24 dev enp2s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.80.5  metric 100
```

Edit 2:

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  10.0.0.0/8           anywhere
```

/etc/default/ufw includes `DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"`.

/etc/ufw/before.rules includes:

```
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0] 
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

Comment: Is the remote machine configured to perform routing between the tunnel interface and its physical interface?  output of `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_foward` on the server?  `ip route` ?

Comment: Edited the question with those answers. Thanks for asking.

Comment: `iptables -t nat -L`  (req sudo, sorry I didn't ask this the first comment).

Comment: Edited again. I don't know much about iptables, but I use ufw, so I included some info about my ufw configuration.

Comment: Could you also add `ip route` output of the client?

Comment: I have a feeling the POSTROUTING line should have a `-o enp2s0` instead of eth0

Comment: Ah! Thank you! That's what I get for following a guide without thinking about everything I copy-pasted.  I'm now able to mount an SMB share from the remote network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I had the wrong interface specified in `/etc/ufw/before.rules`.  I should have had `-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/8 -o enp2s0 -j MASQUERADE` instead of `-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`.  I copy-pasted from a guide without being discerning.